# Scrollbar Visibility issue in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

Scrollbar is not visible in my flex web application when I change the size of window, 
  when i am slightly changing my window size to little bit smaller then, it is not showing any scrollbar and some part of my screen is hidden.
I have already used verticalScrollPolicy and horizontalScrollPolicy in my main mxml file but no effect.Please help me out here.

this is the code.

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
             layout="absolute"
          xmlns:controller="controller.*"
          xmlns:view="view.*"
          width="1000" height="600"
          backgroundColor="#FF9900" 
          verticalScrollPolicy="auto"
          horizontalScrollPolicy="auto">
```

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

change the layout to vertical after that your application tag will going to be like that

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
         layout="vertical"
      xmlns:controller="controller.*"
      xmlns:view="view.*"
      width="1000" height="600"
      backgroundColor="#FF9900" 
      verticalScrollPolicy="auto"
      horizontalScrollPolicy="auto">
```